# How to call multiple constructors inside a single constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I have a running program in c++ where I am dealing with multiple functions, and I am trying to convert program onto an implementation in which constructors can be used. Program looks like below

```
bool netlist::create(const evl_wires &wires,
    const evl_components &comps)
{
    return create_nets(wires)&& create_gates(comps);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires,
    const evl_components &comps)
{
    create(wires, comps);
}
```

where in main function I am calling constructor successfully like this

```
netlist nl(wires, comps);
```

Change I am trying to implement looks like this by adding more constructors

```
netlist::netlist(const evl_components &comps)
{
    create_gates(comps);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires)
{
    create_nets(wires);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires,
    const evl_components &comps)
{
    //this->netlist::netlist(wires);//this approach doesn't work
    //this->netlist::netlist(comps);
    *this = netlist::netlist(wires);//it doesn't work too
    *this = netlist::netlist(comps);
}
```

Examples given on internet websites including this one just show how to call one constructor inside another, how can we call multiple constructors inside one for my example? Other question is when implementation with constructors is better than implementation without constructors keeping in view of my program code?

Comment: `*this = ` will change the `this` point, so doing it twice can't be what you intend

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of relying on random internet tutorials to learn C++.

Comment: Not 100% certain, but it looks like you could be asking about the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: Tell me what `create_nets` does. Does it change the references you send it, or use it?

Comment: @doctorlove create_nets is using another function in it not shown in code above. Code is like one function calls another, other function calls another one and so on. I would like to change code with constructors at all levels, but right now at first level constructor works, at second level which is where problem is right now I am stuck

Comment: How do you expect people to help you when you don't show all of the relevant code? In any case, what the functions do is irrelevant to THIS question which is about calling constructors from other constructors. If you are having other problems, post new questions about THAT.  THIS question has been answered as asked.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is probably [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) (introduced in C++11), in which you can call a constructor in another constructor's member initialization list, eg:

```
netlist::netlist(const evl_components &comps)
{
    create_gates(comps);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires)
{
    create_nets(wires);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires, const evl_components &comps)
    : netlist(wires) // <-- delegating here!
{
    create_gates(comps);
}
```

Note that you can only delegate one constructor at a time, so in the above example, it is not possible for the 2-param constructor to delegate to *both* 1-param constructors.  But, you could swap around the delegation so the 1-param constructors both delegate to the 2-param constructor:

```
netlist::netlist(const evl_components &comps)
    : netlist(evl_wires(), comps)
{
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires)
    : netlist(wires, evl_components())
{
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires, const evl_components &comps)
{
    create_nets(wires);
    create_gates(comps);
}
```

---

However, in your particular example, there is little benefit to delegating any of the constructors at all. Since you already have common functions to initialize the two components, just call them directly:

```
netlist::netlist(const evl_components &comps)
{
    create_gates(comps);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires)
{
    create_nets(wires);
}

netlist::netlist(const evl_wires &wires, const evl_components &comps)
{
    create_nets(wires);
    create_gates(comps);
}
```

Comment: *"error: an initializer for a delegating constructor must appear alone"*

Comment: I tried this approach but at second netlist after comma I see a red line saying a delegation constructor cannot have other mem-initializers .i.e., netlist(comps). That is why my question says multiple constructors not just a single one

Comment: u just used multiple functions in a constructor which works, but how multiple constructors work in one constructor. question can be is it possible, if yes how?

Comment: @aarifboy: "*but how multiple constructors work in one constructor*" - it is not possible, and I had updated my answer to account for that

Comment: In your first solution if I delegate comps instead of wires and use function create_nets instead of create_gates inside body of contructor I see error map/set iterator not dereferencable during run time not during compile time, why would be that?

Comment: btw in create_gates I am using list comps to iterate and in create_nets I am using a map wires to iterate, is it due to that?

Comment: I can't answer that, since you haven't shown any of that relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pre-C++11, you will need to move the common code to separate functions and call them from the constructors.

If you have access to C++11, then use [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor).

Comment: those work for only one constructor, not two or more. that exactly is my question

Comment: @aarifboy: you need to move the common code, that is, both constructors into one separate function each; then call from each of the 3 constructors the other 2 functions as needed -- that is, if you are using pre-C++11.